# scrapy crawler caught exception reading instance data

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to python and want to use scrapy to build a web crawler. I go through the tutorial in http://blog.siliconstraits.vn/building-web-crawler-scrapy/. Spider code likes following:

```
from scrapy.spider         import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector         import HtmlXPathSelector
from nettuts.items        import NettutsItem
from scrapy.http        import Request

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
     name         = "nettuts"
     allowed_domains    = ["net.tutsplus.com"]
     start_urls    = ["http://net.tutsplus.com/"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs     = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles     = hxs.select('//h1[@class="post_title"]/a/text()').extract()
    for title in titles:
        item = NettutsItem()
        item["title"] = title
        yield item
```

When launch the spider with command line: scrapy crawl nettus, it has following error:

```
[boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2015-07-05 18:27:17 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)

 File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
response = self._open(req, data)

 File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
'_open', req)

 File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)

 File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)

File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
raise URLError(err)

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>
2015-07-05 18:27:17 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
```

really do not know what's wrong. Hope somebody could help

Comment: Is that the full traceback (I'm guessing it's not)/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

in the settings.py file: add following code settings:

DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {'s3': None,}

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: Could someone explain what was going wrong here? and how did answer fix it?

Comment: Worked for me. No idea why, nor if there's any docs for that. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @printemp I love you! After many and many hours of trying I have finally resolved that. Only thanks to you.

Comment: @printemp any chance you can get some more details about what this does? It does in fact work for me - but i would love to understand it as well ;)

Comment: This worked for me, but seriously whats happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The important information is:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>
```

That is trying to tell you that your computer doesn't know how to communicate with the site you're trying to scrape. Are you able to access the site normally (i.e. in a web-browser) from the machine you're trying to run this python on?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to help you further. All I can say is that "No route to host" is a networking problem telling you that the OS doesn't know how to send packets to the IP address it needs to send packets to.